# Django - How am I using python map incorrectly?

Tags: python, django

I am receiving a Type error from `django` in my view code.
While attempting to round up to the nearest 5. i.e. 7 becomes 10 or 123 becomes 125, etc

I have a list of integers

```
valList = [ int(i) for i in str(int(math.ceil(result))) ]
```

I then change a digit

```
valList[len(valList)-1] = 5
```

and then combine the values to create a whole integer again.

```
result = ''.join(map(str, valList))
```

then cast back to an int

```
result = int(result)
```

This method works when I use the python console (and in the django shell) but when I run this is my django view I get a `TypeError Exception` the error is `map() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)`

I cannot figure out what is causing this....Or what I am doing wrong.

Thanks.

p.s. If anybody knows of an elegant solution to round to the nearest 5 I'm all ears.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about a mathematical solution:

```
>>> def f(n):
...   q, r = divmod(n,5)
...   if r == 0:
...     return q * 5
...   else:
...     return (q * 5) + 5
...
>>> f(7)
10
>>> f(123)
125
>>> f(120)
120
```

Comment: This works perfectly. I tried moding originally with the last digit but failed. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The generic way to round up to a number, with integer math, is:

```
(((number - 1) // base) + 1) * base
```

Replace the `//` with `/` for other languages.

To access the last item of a list

```
valList[-1] = 5
```

Finally, you've got some other `map` in your namespace. Find it and rename it.

Comment: Why do you need floor division `//` instead of just division `/`?

Comment: Just so that you get an `int` out even if you put a `float` in. I think that's the expected behavior.

Comment: nice. I think your solution is more elegant than mine, and I've +1ed it. However, I personally find mine easier to understand.

Comment: Yep, yours is very straightforward if you know what `divmod` does.

Comment: I definitely had another map in my namespace. It was hiding and I was tired. @MattH method is a bit easier to understand. But I have committed your answer to memory. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First off, `valList[len(valList)-1]` should be written as `valList[-1]`. About the arguments problem, check if `map` has been replaced by another function, because `map() requires at least two args` in my python console.